# jinja2: render template without extend

Tags: jinja2

How I can render template without extend? i have simple renderer and i want after findout this request is ajax just render goal data

my template:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load i18n %}

{% block extrahead %}
{% endblock extrahead %}


{% block content %}

  <div class="itemBg">
    <div class="itemTop">
      <div class="itemDown">

        <div class="rowContainer">
            <div class="show att">
                {{ msg }}
            </div>
        </div>

</div></div></div>
{% endblock %}
```

only i want this in render response for ajax request.

```
  <div class="itemBg">
    <div class="itemTop">
      <div class="itemDown">

        <div class="rowContainer">
            <div class="show att">
                {{ msg }}
            </div>
        </div>

</div></div></div>
```

this is my render interface

```
from flask import current_app, render_template

def render(template, **context):
    """
    """
    return render_template(path(template), **context)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are looking for the [null-master fallback](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/tricks/#null-master-fallback) trick.  Since `request` is available in the Jinja2 context, if you are using a library that sets the appropriate header you can simply do this:

```
{% if not request.is_xhr %}{% extends "base.html" %}{% endif -%}
{% load i18n %}
{% block content %}

  <div class="itemBg">
    <div class="itemTop">
      <div class="itemDown">

        <div class="rowContainer">
            <div class="show att">
                {{ msg }}
            </div>
        </div>

</div></div></div>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the block you want for AJAX in a separate template.

When you get an AJAX request, just render that new template. For non-AJAX requests, include it in the one that extends base.html.

Comment: i think maybe better this append to jinja, i think 2 template a little dirty coding.

Comment: Then extending a "base.html" is just as dirty, no?

Comment: no its for reduce count of html file. do you belive remove extend for ajax request is not big deal?