# django template conditional extend

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates, syntax-error

I have a very specific issue. I'm using a [maintenance mode](https://pypi.org/project/django-maintenance-mode/) to get a built-in 503 view. I can customize the template in any way I want. I got it working, however I want the template to extend the admin base template when the request.path is /admin. When it isn't it should extend the normal base template.

I tried it with this:

```
{% if '/beheerpaneel' in request.path %}
    {% extends "admin/index.html" %}
{% else %}
    {% extends "base.html" %}
{% endif %}
```

but that gives me a template syntax error, because the extend tag must be first. After some googling it seems I need to handle this in the view.. but there is no view, its built-in. Anyone know a way around this? In the future I also wanna do this with the 404 and 500 pages etc.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11412948/jinja2-render-template-without-extend

Answer (score 0):

You should do that in the context. So in your view, you can work with:

```
def my_view(request):
    if '/beheerpaneel' in request.path:
        template_base = 'admin/index.html'
    else:
        template_base = 'base.html'
    # …
    return render(request, 'your-template.html', {'template_base': template_base})
```

and then render this with:

```
{% extends template_base %}
<!-- ... -->
```

Comment: I don't have a view to work with, it's built-in